# status bar is overlaps on view in ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7, statusbar

[image]   [image]

status bar is good work in navigation base application but when i use presentModelViewController then status bar will be 
overlap.

Comment: please provide image of that overlapped status bar.

Answer (score 0):

write below code in viewdidload:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```